# How to install NGINX on AWS EC2 Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2

I'm new to AWS and trying to understand which version of NGINX I should be installing on my instance. I've found multiple options;

- Via [EPEL](https://comtechies.com/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-on-amazon-ec2-rhel-and-ubuntu-instances.html) as the blog entry
- Amazon's own (?) version as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199858/6076861)
- The 2016 NGINX official [tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/blog/setting-up-nginx/)

On my development environment (Centos VM) I used `sudo yum install nginx`. Having tried the EPEL route I don't get the same set up, in particular sites enabled/available is not created as part of the setup. I want to use [nginxconfig.io](https://nginxconfig.io/) which requires those. Which version of NGINX should i use for that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'd personally use Amazon's own repo.

The version provided by the Amazon repo is relatively old (`1.12.2` at the time of writing). To see what versions the Amazon repo has access to run

```
amazon-linux-extras list | grep nginx
```

If you'd like a later version, consider EPEL.

In regards to the config, your best bet is to explicitly supply the configuration you require to the server.

Using the off-the-peg ones are fine to get you up and running. However you run the risk of things changing when Nginx updates. Explicitly supplying your own configuration gives you greater control over what is running.

Probably the simplest approach would be to upload the configuration generated by `nginxconfig.io` to S3.

Then add a script via user data when creating the EC2 instance to download your configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Something like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install Nginx
amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.12

# Back up existing config
mv /etc/nginx /etc/nginx-backup

# Download the configuration from S3
aws s3 cp s3://{my_bucket}/nginxconfig.io-example.com.zip /tmp

# Install new configuration
unzip /tmp/nginxconfig.io-example.com.zip -d /etc/nginx
```

The configuration supplied by `nginxconfig.io` sets up all the sites enabled/available for you.

Comment: Thanks Mat, is that nginx1.12 an AWS variant, or is it just behind current nginx which is 1.17?

Comment: Its pretty old, however its the latest they supply though this channel

`amazon-linux-extras list | grep nginx`

Comment: If you want to use a latest then go down the EPEL route. Everything from 

```
# Back up existing config
mv /etc/nginx /etc/nginx-backup
``` 
remains the same

Comment: Thanks, I think that's worth noting in your answer

Comment: They no longer list versions in the `amazon-linux-extras` output, just `=stable`.  Did the install, and the current version is `1.18.0-1.amzn2.0.2`

Comment: How can i uninstall this?

Answer (score 125):

Alternative way to install that could be easier (has a fairly recent version of Nginx):

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras list | grep nginx
 38  nginx1=latest            disabled      [ =stable ]

$ sudo amazon-linux-extras enable nginx1
 38  nginx1=latest            enabled      [ =stable ]
        
Now you can install:
$ sudo yum clean metadata
$ sudo yum -y install nginx
    
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
```

Comment: `sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y nginx1` will enable and install the package from extras.

Comment: You can add `systemctl start nginx` to start it and `systemctl enable nginx` to start it at reboot.