# No nginx folders after installing on Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, yum, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to install Nginx on an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2. After running the commands as listed here on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256478/11309912.

Checking the version shows that is installed.

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.22.0
```

But either under `/etc` or `/local` there is no nginx folder being created.

`nginx -t` does run but fails:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2022/11/13 13:33:46 [emerg] 16016#16016: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I tried running `sudo yum remove nginx` and `sudo yum install nginx`/`sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y nginx1` but both to no avail.

Is there a way to (re)install nginx that places these folders and configs?

Answer (score 1):

The default document root directory for Nginx on Ubuntu and Debian is /var/www/html, while on CentOS and RHEL it is **/usr/share/nginx/html**. This is where you should place your web content, such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files.

so i think the location you are looking for is **/usr/share/nginx/html**

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed nginx on Amazon Linux 2 using amazon-linux-extras, i.e, the following command -

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
```

The configuration will be located in the **/etc/nginx** directory and the static files will be located in the **/usr/share/nginx/html** directory.